# I have a error : Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Tags: flutter, gradle

I have a  'Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1' error. I tried many solution here but it didnt work. I tried to change the gradle version. I wrote the latest version of gradle in the gradle-wrapper properties but i still have a same error. Is there anyone to help?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rk8Ly.png)

[gradle-wrapper properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVJws.png)

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJfDU.png)

Comment: [Never post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: try downgrading or upgrading  photo_manager.

Comment: Add `-s` flag for you Gradle commands to get error stacktrace, so people can know what exactly it is.

Comment: i dont know how to do that so i just follow the instruction. i will try @RiggsFolly